# how to load navigations immediately when loading table

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have two classes: User and Ticket, and DBContext

```
    public class Ticket
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public long UserId { get; set; }       
        public User User { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class User
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    }

    public class Database : DbContext
    {
        public Database() { }

        public Database(DbContextOptions<Database> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=server;port=port;user=user;password=password;database=mydb");
        }
    }
```

And there are two tables in MySQL with corresponding fields. I need to make one-to-many relationship between users and tickets tables. UserId in the Ticket class is a ForeignKey in the tickets table, referring to the users table on the id property. `public User User` is a navigation property.

I need to call `context.Tickets.Include(t => t.User)` to make the `User` in the `Ticket` class non-null (on start-up the value of User is null), but the `UserId` already has a value before the call. Can I make it so that `User` is defined immediately and I don't need to call `context.Tickets.Include(t => t.User)`?

I tried to set links between the tables directly using the method described in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**: you need active lazy loading

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("..")
    }
```

**Solution 2**: using AutoInclude

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
          .Navigation(e => e.User)
           .AutoInclude();
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between these solutions? I've heard that with lazy loading the navigation field only becomes defined when you access it. With the second approach, will the navigation field be loaded immediately?

Comment: The first solution will load the navigation fields of all DbSet objects without the need for any settings when calling the DbSet. The second solution is only applicable to the Ticket table.